# Can we overwrite SSM parameter from CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

Let's say I have stack-1 as

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  BasicParameter:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
    Properties:
      Name: "commands"
      Type: "StringList"
      Value: "date,ls"
```

And then stack-2 as :

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  BasicParameter:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
    Properties:
      Name: "commands"
      Type: "StringList"
      Value: "pwd"
```

On creating a new stack, I am getting an error that parameter already exists. We can overwrite parameters using aws cli 'put-parameter --overwrite'. Can we do something similar with CloudFormation template?

Comment: A resource defined in a CF template will be created as new. If you want to be able to update an SSM parameter used by multiple stacks, I'd suggest you centralise/externalise its creation, then you can update it as desired from that stack. Otherwise you could create a custom resource that will do the update for the specified SSM parameter.

Comment: @404 Thanks for your response. I ended up centralizing ssm parameter for now.